# Get.to(...) method returns me a black screen - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, get, screen, navigator

I'm trying to use the Get package as a sort of Navigator but when I want to go to another page, the app returns me a black page, with a big X on it.

[The black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMRBB.png)

Here the code of the main:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: MyAppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: MyAppTheme.darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
```

My SplashScreen:
(note the startAnimation() method at the beginning, right before the Scaffold)

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SplashScreen({super.key});

  final splashScreenController = Get.put(SplashScreenController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    splashScreenController.startAnimation();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(
        () => AnimatedOpacity(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          opacity: splashScreenController.animate.value ? 1 : 0,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Obx(
                () =>  AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  top: splashScreenController.animate.value ? -20 : -30,
                  left: splashScreenController.animate.value ? -20 : -50,
                  width: 170,
                  height: 170,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(iconaCerchioBlu),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Obx(
                () => AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  top: splashScreenController.animate.value ? 190 : 160,
                  left: splashScreenController.animate.value ? 100 : 120,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  child: const Image(
                    image: AssetImage(iconaCerchioVerde),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  top: 520,
                  left: 0,
                  height: 170,
                  width: 390,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          myAppName,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          myAppTagLine,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              Obx(
                () => AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  top: splashScreenController.animate.value ? 700 : 750,
                  left: splashScreenController.animate.value ? 0 : 30,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(iconaCerchioBlu),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My SplashScreenController:
(It should move the focus on the page to next Widget after 5 seconds, but it doesn't work)

```
class SplashScreenController extends GetxController {
  static SplashScreenController get find => Get.find();
  RxBool animate = false.obs;

  Future startAnimation() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)); //0.5s
    animate.value = true;
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    Get.to(() => WelcomeScreen());
  }
}
```

And the Welcome() page:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Placeholder(
      child: Text(
        "Ciao, sono la schermata Home",
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've already tried to use
Get.to( () => WelcomeScreen() ) instead of what I've put in the code above.

Have you got and idea of the reason of that?
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Randal and for your advice, but it doesn't really answer my question. I'v seen the video you suggested and I'm interested in using good and reliable packages, but I'm also interested in know why my code doesn't work.